# angular ui-sortable offset on drag if page scrolled before

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, angular-ui-sortable

I have found that if a page is scrollable, after scroll if intended to drag and drop an item(in order to sort an ng-repeat list) then the dragged element appears with as much offset on the y-axis as distance I have scrolled down the page before dragging the element.

I am using:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable

The issue is documented here:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable/issues/286

I don't seem to be able to call the ui.item.sort('refreshPosition') method. Neither sure if should do so by editing the original code, or in my own controller!?

This is my relevant template code:

```
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="form_field_ref2">
  <div ng-init="tmp = dbo.get(attobj.name)" ng-controller="sortController">
   <!-- <div ng-model="tmp" ui-sortable="{ 'ui-floating': 'auto'}">-->
    <div ng-model="tmp" ui-sortable="sortableOptions">
      <div ng-repeat="dbo2 in dbo.get(attobj.name) track by $index" id="sort_{{$index}}" style="float:left; padding-right: 3px; padding-bottom: 5px;">
        <div class="tag sortableTag">
          <a href="#/view/{{ dbo2.cid }}" target="_blank">{{ dbo2.displayName() }}</a>
          <a href="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="dbo.removeValue(attobj.name, $index)"></a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div ng-include="'typeaheadtemplate2'" style="width: 100%;"></div>
</script>
```

controller:

```
app.controller('sortController', function ($scope) {

  $scope.sortableOptions = {
    'ui-floating': 'auto',
    activate: function() {
        console.log("activate");
    },
    beforeStop: function() {
        console.log("beforeStop");
    },
    change: function() {
        console.log("change");
    },
    create: function() {
        console.log("create");
    },
    deactivate: function() {
        console.log("deactivate");
    },
    out: function() {
        console.log("out");
    },
    over: function() {
        console.log("over");
    },
    receive: function() {
        console.log("receive");
    },
    remove: function() {
        console.log("remove");
    },
    sort: function() {
        console.log("sort");
    },
    start: function(e, ui) {
        console.log("start");
        console.log(ui.item);
        var tag= '#'+ui.item.context.id;
        $(tag).sortable('refreshPositions');
        // $(this).sortable('refreshPositions');
    },
    update: function(e, ui) {
      console.log("update");

    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
      console.log("stop");

    }
  };
});
```

Attempt to drag the highlighted tag in blue:
[image]

Appears with an offset by respect of the mouse cursor which is in the tags original position(sorry the cursor doesn't appear on image):
[image]

Error with unique selector id:
[image]

Comment: Why can't you specify sortable options in your controller and call refresh position on the start event callback as mentioned in the github issue..?

Comment: I all ways get sort is not a function!

Comment: Then you should post the [mcve] causing the problem.

Comment: I'll add the controller with the start event

Comment: @TJ I have added controller and log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that, you're trying to invoke `refreshPositions` on `ui.item.sortable` which is an object that ui-sortable uses to store data. You should call `refreshPositions` on the element which is sortable.

try

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="form_field_ref2">
  <div ng-init="tmp = dbo.get(attobj.name)" ng-controller="sortController">
   <!-- <div ng-model="tmp" ui-sortable="{ 'ui-floating': 'auto'}">-->
    <div ng-model="tmp" ui-sortable="sortableOptions">
      <div ng-repeat="dbo2 in dbo.get(attobj.name) track by $index" style="float:left; padding-right: 3px; padding-bottom: 5px;">
        <div class="tag sortableTag">
          <a href="#/view/{{ dbo2.cid }}" target="_blank">{{ dbo2.displayName() }}</a>
          <a href="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="dbo.removeValue(attobj.name, $index)"></a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div ng-include="'typeaheadtemplate2'" style="width: 100%;"></div>
</script>
```

controller:

```
app.controller('sortController', function ($scope) {

   $scope.sortableOptions = {
                start: function(event, ui) {
                    $(this).sortable({
                            sort: function(event, ui) {
                                var $target = $(event.target);
                                if (!/html|body/i.test($target.offsetParent()[0].tagName)) {
                                    var top = event.pageY - $target.offsetParent().offset().top - (ui.helper.outerHeight(true) / 2);
                                    ui.helper.css({'top' : top + 'px'});
                                }
                            }
                    });

                }
            };


});
```

Comment: with $this same behavior persists and if I use a unique selector I get a: "Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on sortable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refreshPositions'" error and any content after the draged tag slides down the page as I hold the tag(mouse down and move cursor)

Comment: I have added both versions to controller

Comment: Changes added in question

Comment: @AlExTsm you're getting the error because your selector is wrong. If it is the element which is initialized as sortable, you won't get that error. `$(this)` is working, but it doesn't fix your problem. Try adding the other suggestions (rest of code) in the github solution

Comment: The second option on https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable/issues/286 worked among your $(this) selector. If u add it to the answer I can accept it!

Comment: just the "start:" event part!

Answer (score 6):

Adding style

```
overflow-y: auto;
```

to the sortable item fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".sortable").sortable({
      sort: function(event, ui) {
           ui.position.top = ui.position.top + $(window).scrollTop();
      },
});
```

and add "position: relative" sortable block